# set value from select for few select

Tags: t-sql

I have select, iside select have 2 column. This column must be filled from same select, but I don't want use select twice for it. Is it possoble use select 1 time and after that set second column value from first?
Example:

```
insert into @temptable from 
select
a = (select aa from table1 where quantity > 5)
b = (select aa from table1 where quantity > 5)
```

I need:

```
insert into @temptable from 
select
a = (select aa from table1 where quantity > 5)
b = {value from a}
```

Update. I wrote bad example, I need set to BalancePrediction1 and BalancePrediction2 value from Balance

```
INSERT @tmpBalances
        SELECT PA.ContractId AS 'ContractId',
            Con.Name AS 'ContractName',
            Bal.PortfolioAccountId AS 'PortfolioAccountId',
            PA.Name AS 'PortfolioAccountName',
            RA.GeneralId AS 'RegisterAccountGeneralId',
            Bal.BalanceTypeId AS 'BalanceTypeId',
            Bt.Name AS 'BalanceTypeName',
            Bt.Type AS 'BalanceTypeType',
            Bal.BalanceTimeType AS 'BalanceTimeType',
            Bal.InstrumentId AS 'InstrumentId',
            Ins.Name AS 'InstrumentName',
            Ins.GeneralId AS 'InstrumentGeneralId',
            (Bal.Balance - 
                (       
                    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Mov.Amount), 0)
                      FROM trd.Movements AS Mov 
                    WHERE   
                        Bal.InstrumentId = Mov.InstrumentId AND
                        Bal.PortfolioAccountId = Mov.PortfolioAccountId AND
                        Bal.BalanceTypeId = Mov.BalanceTypeId AND
                        Bal.BalanceTimeType = Mov.BalanceTimeType AND
                        DateDiff(DAY, @Date, Mov.Date) > 0 AND
                        -- Currency může být null a NULL = NULL nejde
                        COALESCE(Bal.CurrencyId, -1) = COALESCE(Mov.CurrencyId, -1)
                )
            ) as Balance,
            Balance AS 'BalancePrediction1',
            Balance AS 'BalancePrediction2',
            Bal.CurrencyId AS 'CurrencyId',
            Ccy.Code AS 'CurrencyCode',
            PA.PositionServiceType 'PositionServiceType',
            Ccy.Name 'CurrencyName',
            S.Nominal AS 'Nominal',
            S.NominalCurrencyId AS 'NominalCurrencyId',
            trd.GetCurrencyCode(S.NominalCurrencyId) AS 'NominalCurrencyCode'
          FROM trd.Balances AS Bal
            JOIN trd.PortfolioAccounts AS PA ON PA.Id = Bal.PortfolioAccountId
            JOIN trd.Contracts AS Con ON Con.Id = PA.ContractId
            JOIN trd.RegisterAccounts AS RA ON RA.Id = PA.RegisterAccountId
            JOIN trd.BalanceTypes AS Bt ON Bt.Id = Bal.BalanceTypeId
            JOIN trd.Instruments AS Ins ON Ins.Id = Bal.InstrumentId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN trd.Currencies AS Ccy ON Ccy.Id = Bal.CurrencyId
            LEFT JOIN trd.SecuritiesView S ON s.Id = Ins.Id AND DateDiff(d, S.ValidFrom, @Date) >= 0 AND (S.ValidTo IS NULL OR DateDiff(d, S.ValidTo, @Date) < 0)
                AND S.InstrumentInstrumentTypePriceUnit = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do an update to the table variable after the insert.

```
update @tmpBalances
set BalancePrediction1 = Balance,
    BalancePrediction2 = Balance
```

Or you can use `cross apply` to calculate the sum.

```
INSERT @tmpBalances
        SELECT PA.ContractId AS 'ContractId',
            Con.Name AS 'ContractName',
            Bal.PortfolioAccountId AS 'PortfolioAccountId',
            PA.Name AS 'PortfolioAccountName',
            RA.GeneralId AS 'RegisterAccountGeneralId',
            Bal.BalanceTypeId AS 'BalanceTypeId',
            Bt.Name AS 'BalanceTypeName',
            Bt.Type AS 'BalanceTypeType',
            Bal.BalanceTimeType AS 'BalanceTimeType',
            Bal.InstrumentId AS 'InstrumentId',
            Ins.Name AS 'InstrumentName',
            Ins.GeneralId AS 'InstrumentGeneralId',
            (Bal.Balance - Mov.SumAmount) AS Balance,
            (Bal.Balance - Mov.SumAmount) AS 'BalancePrediction1',
            (Bal.Balance - Mov.SumAmount) AS 'BalancePrediction2',
            Bal.CurrencyId AS 'CurrencyId',
            Ccy.Code AS 'CurrencyCode',
            PA.PositionServiceType 'PositionServiceType',
            Ccy.Name 'CurrencyName',
            S.Nominal AS 'Nominal',
            S.NominalCurrencyId AS 'NominalCurrencyId',
            trd.GetCurrencyCode(S.NominalCurrencyId) AS 'NominalCurrencyCode'
          FROM trd.Balances AS Bal
            JOIN trd.PortfolioAccounts AS PA ON PA.Id = Bal.PortfolioAccountId
            JOIN trd.Contracts AS Con ON Con.Id = PA.ContractId
            JOIN trd.RegisterAccounts AS RA ON RA.Id = PA.RegisterAccountId
            JOIN trd.BalanceTypes AS Bt ON Bt.Id = Bal.BalanceTypeId
            JOIN trd.Instruments AS Ins ON Ins.Id = Bal.InstrumentId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN trd.Currencies AS Ccy ON Ccy.Id = Bal.CurrencyId
            LEFT JOIN trd.SecuritiesView S ON s.Id = Ins.Id AND DateDiff(d, S.ValidFrom, @Date) >= 0 AND (S.ValidTo IS NULL OR DateDiff(d, S.ValidTo, @Date) < 0)
                AND S.InstrumentInstrumentTypePriceUnit = 1
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Mov.Amount), 0)
                         FROM trd.Movements AS Mov 
                         WHERE   
                            Bal.InstrumentId = Mov.InstrumentId AND
                            Bal.PortfolioAccountId = Mov.PortfolioAccountId AND
                            Bal.BalanceTypeId = Mov.BalanceTypeId AND
                            Bal.BalanceTimeType = Mov.BalanceTimeType AND
                            DateDiff(DAY, @Date, Mov.Date) > 0 AND
                            -- Currency může být null a NULL = NULL nejde
                            COALESCE(Bal.CurrencyId, -1) = COALESCE(Mov.CurrencyId, -1)
                        ) Mov(SumAmount)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT aa AS a, aa AS b
FROM table1
WHERE quantity > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way;

```
;with T (value) as (
    select aa from table1 where quantity > 5
)
insert into @temptable 
    select value, value from T
```